# Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exception, collections

I am using a collection to display data in my view but it generates following error message

```
FatalErrorException in 47fef8438385ff37fab794239c1e3914 line 0:
Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception
```

when i code like

```
{{ $feed->feedable->slug->value }}
```

on the other hand, when i use below given code,

```
{{ $feed->feedable->slug }}
```

it works fine and returns

```
{"id":3,"value":"Quite","views":5,"user_id":1,"category_id":1,"created_at":"2016-05-23 14:18:03","updated_at":"2016-05-24 12:47:29"}
```

Can any one please provide the solution?

Comment: Is your `slug` a json string? If so, you'll need to `json_decode()` it first and then do `->slug` on that.

Comment: Do you have any custom accessors on your Slug model?

Comment: i dont have any coustom error on slug model

Comment: no, its a laravel collection. for ease it is output as json

Comment: So it's a collection containing a single object which contains the slug?

Comment: Does your feedable->slug has one to many relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert a View to a string in your view. Which is not in the code provided.

That view is causing an exception.

Missing code from view:

`{!! View::make('partials.my._singleFeedDynamic', compact('feed'))  !!}`

You should not be doing this from a view. There is `@include` and `@each` for including partials like this.

If you don't want to fix that you can try to add `->render()` to that call to avoid the `__toString()` that is happening. That will allow the exception to bubble like normal. Then you will have to figure out what is causing that exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try outputting the value like this:

```
{{ $feed->feedable->slug->getOriginal('value') }}
```

Comment: Call to a member function getOriginal() on a non-object

Comment: Can you update your question to include the relevant models (Feedable and Slug)